# Validation in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, validation, oledbdataadapter

here i am putting a bulk data in table of more then 5000+

```
  using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        {
            excel_con.Open();
            string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();





            dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[10] {

//this are my columns of records

            new DataColumn("Employee Code",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Employee Type", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("First Name", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Last Name", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Gender",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Email ID", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Mobile No#", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Current Address", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Permanent Address", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Status",typeof(string))
        }
            );


            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);


            }
            excel_con.Close();
```

now before inserting or after insert in datatable 
i want to check validation of Mobile No,Email ID,Gender,null value etc

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use this code

```
 using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
              if(dtExcelData.rows.count<0)
               {
               for(int i=0;i<dtExcelData.rows.count;i++)
                {
                  string mobno=dtExcelData.rows[i]["Mobile No#"].tostring();
                    if(mobno=="")
                     {
                       //code here 
                         }
                  }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

we can validate data before insert it.if bool is true proceed data to insert else rejected.

```
         public bool ValidateData(DataTable dtData)
            {
                bool isValid = true;
                try
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < dtData.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string MANDATE_DATE = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["MANDATE_DATE"]);
                        //string SPONSOR_BANK_CODE = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["SPONSOR_BANK_CODE"]);
                        //string UTILITY_BILLER_COMPANY_BANK = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["UTILITY_BILLER_COMPANY_BANK"]);
                        //string ACTION = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["ACTION"]);
                        string AC_TYPE = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["AC_TYPE"]);
                        string LEGAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["LEGAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER"]);
                        string DESTINATION_BANK_BRANCH = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["DESTINATION_BANK_BRANCH"]);
                        string MICR_CODE = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["MICR_CODE"]);
                        //string IFSC_CODE = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["IFSC_CODE"]);
                        string DEBIT_MAXAMT = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["DEBIT_MAXAMT"]);
                        string CUSTOMER_REFERENCE = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["CUSTOMER_REFERENCE"]);
                        string CUSTOMER_FRQCY = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["CUSTOMER_FRQCY"]);
                        string START_DATE = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["START_DATE"]);
                        // string END_DATE = dtData.Rows[i]["Mobile No#"]);
                        string CUSTOMER_NAME = Convert.ToString(dtData.Rows[i]["CUSTOMER_NAME"]);

                        if (MANDATE_DATE == "" || AC_TYPE == "" || LEGAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER == "" || DESTINATION_BANK_BRANCH == "" || MICR_CODE == "" || DEBIT_MAXAMT == "" || CUSTOMER_REFERENCE == "" || CUSTOMER_FRQCY == "" || START_DATE == "" || CUSTOMER_NAME == "")
                        {
                            SchedulerErrorLog_("Mandatory field is blank", "Function: testTimer_Elapsed (ValidateData)");
                            //ErrorLog(product_Name, path, "Failure", "File name  " + path + " Data is not validate.", "");
                            return isValid = false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!isValid)
                    {
                        //dtExport = dtData.Copy();`enter code here`
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    SchedulerErrorLog_(ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                    //ErrorLog(product_Name, path, "Failure", "File name  " + path + " Data is not validate." + ex.ToString() + "", "");
                    throw ex;
                }
                return isValid;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use DataView class that is initialized with reference of DataTable.
writing filter options to DataView.

Answer (score 0):

DataTable supports setting error text for columns or rows, using [SetColumnError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.setcolumnerror?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method and [RowError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.rowerror?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) properties of DataRow.

- Set a column error: When column value of a row is invalid; for example, when value of the first name is null; if the price is negative; if the email format is not valid.
- Set a row error: When combination of the column values is not valid; for example, when the start date is after the end date; when either one column or the other column should have value, if the status of the row is invalid. Or for example you can combine all the column errors, and set a single row error instead.

Using those properties to set/remove validation errors give you a good integration with windows forms controls like DataGridView or ErrorProvider, because the DataRowView class implements IDataErrorInfo interface based on the error text of the columns and rows.

**Example - Validate DataTable**

Here is an example:

```
//Returns true if the row is valid, otherwise it returns false
private bool ValidateDataRow(DataRow dr)
{
    var column1 = "Column1";
    if (dr[column1] == null || dr[column1] == DBNull.Value)
        dr.SetColumnError(column1, "Required");
    else
        dr.SetColumnError(column1, null);

    //Other validations

    return dr.HasErrors;
}
//Returns true if all the columns and rows are valid, otherwise returns false
private bool ValidateDataTable(DataTable dt)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        ValidateDataRow(dr);
    return dt.HasErrors;
}
```

**Example - Validating DataTable in Windows Forms**

To show the errors on cells or rows of DataGridView, set [ShowRowErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.showrowerrors?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and [ShowCellErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.showcellerrors?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to true. Then when saving the data, call `ValidateDataTable`:

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Validate all cells
    if (!ValidateDataTable(dataTable))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fix validation errors");
        return;
    }

    //Save changes;
}
```

You may also want to update validation status of the cells and rows after editing cells:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{ 
    ValidateDataRow(((DataRowView)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row);
}
```