# How to detect empty space in datagridview and warn the screen if it is empty?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

- I want only 3 of the columns in my table in Datagridview1 not to be empty. I want it to warn the screen when there is an empty field.
- I tried to make a mandatory field to be filled in the datagridview1 table
- When I add other data to the data I pull from sql in Datagridview, I want it to warn the screen to be filled if there should be no empty space.
- As you can see in the photo below, only those places should not be empty, and when I press save, it should detect when there is an empty space and give a warning to the screen.
- give a warning if there is free space

```
        private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Envanter where BilgNo,VarlikSahibi,IP", baglanti);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BilgNo", dataGridView1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VarlikSahibi", dataGridView1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IP", dataGridView1);

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {



                commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(tablo);
                MessageBox.Show("Saved");
                Envanter();


                return;
                
                /*
                if (dataGridView1.Rows.Cells[1].Value == null | Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value) | string.IsNullOrEmpty)
                {
                    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("pls no empty", "Warn!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }

                return;
                */
                
            }

        }
```

[image]

Comment: I just want the 3 columns in the table to be blank impassable fields, when I write something under the columns and say save, the recording should be successful, if it is empty and the save button is pressed, it should write the name of that column and give a warning. (I ONLY USE DATAGRIDVİEW, NOTHING ELSE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using plain C# model classes, you can rely on [data annotations validation attributes](https://www.reza-aghaei.com/dataannotations-validation-attributes-in-windows-forms/).

If you are using DataTable as the model, you can [validate the DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74941404/3110834) by setting column or row errors and check if the data table has errors.

You can also look over the rows or cells of DataGridView and set cell or row errors, with or without databinding.

**Example - Validating Cells of DataGridView and show error on cells**

```
private bool ValidateCell(DataGridViewCell cell)
{
    //Validation rules for Column 1
    if (cell.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        if (cell.Value == null ||
            cell.Value == DBNull.Value ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()))
        {
            cell.ErrorText = "Required";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.ErrorText = null;
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Other validations
    return true;
}
private bool ValidateDataGridView(DataGridView dgv)
{
    return dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where(r => !r.IsNewRow)
        .SelectMany(r => r.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>())
        .Select(c => ValidateCell(c)).ToList()
        .All(x => x == true);
}
```

Then use above methods before saving the data:

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ValidateDataGridView(dataGridView1))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fix validation errors");
        return;
    }
    //Save changes;
}
```

To show the errors on cells or rows of DataGridView, set [ShowRowErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.showrowerrors?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and [ShowCellErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.showcellerrors?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to true.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.ShowCellErrors = true;
```

Also, if you want to update the validations of the cells, after editing the cell:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    ValidateCell(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Rıza Ağai

I think these are codes for validation, when I enter a data in the datagrid I want it to save it, if there is no data I want it not to save it and give a warning to fill that field, but it didn't work.

Comment: The example has both: `DataGridView1_CellValueChanged` does the validation while you type (so that it shows the errors immediately, if you don't like it, don't use it. `SaveButton_Click`, on the other hand, does the validation and show the errors on DataGridView and shows a message box.

Answer (score 1):

First Iterate over the dataset rows and  then iterate over the value of each cell if there are any empty values return the message box of your choice to the user. Please find the below attached code for your reference.

**You can do the following :**

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rw.Cells.Count; i++)
  {
    if (rw.Cells[i].Value == null || rw.Cells[i].Value == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rw.Cells[i].Value.ToString())
    {
      // here is your input message box...
        string promptValue = Prompt.ShowDialog("Message", "some other string you want!");
    }
    else 
    {
      // Proceed with the things you want to do..
    }
  } 
}
```

**And use the below code to create an input popup:**

```
public static class Prompt
{
    public static string ShowDialog(string text, string caption)
    {
        Form prompt = new Form()
        {
            Width = 500,
            Height = 150,
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
            Text = caption,
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        };
        Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top=20, Text=text };
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top=50, Width=400 };
        Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left=350, Width=100, Top=70, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
        confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
        prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
        prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
        prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
        prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;

        return prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? textBox.Text : "";
    }
}
```

**And you can call it using :**

```
string promptValue = Prompt.ShowDialog("Message", "some other string you want!");
```

Comment: Hi, Selaka Nanayakkara

Only if the fields I have marked in the picture are empty, it should give a warning that it cannot be left empty, it should be filled, how can I do it and how the code layout should be

Comment: In the condition succeeds then it means you have an empty value.. then you can proceed with an input text box. If not then proceed with whatever you want in the else block. I updated the answer. appreciate giving it an upvote and marking It as correct.

Comment: Hi, Selaka Nanayakkara 


I am using VisualStudio VisualBasic codes did not work

Comment: Hi, selaka nanayakkara please read my comment.

Comment: Ive added C# codes to resolve the above. Please check